# CouchDb certificate

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, couchdb

I'm currently trying to get my CouchDb installation up and running with a SSL certificate.
My configuration is as follows:

```
[ssl]
port = 6984
enable = true
cert_file = /ssl/self.crt
key_file = /ssl/self.key
;password = N3sHfhgV4
; set to true to validate peer certificates
;verify_ssl_certificates = false
; Set to true to fail if the client does not send a certificate. Only used if verify_ssl_certificates is true.
;fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
; Path to file containing PEM encoded CA certificates (trusted
; certificates used for verifying a peer certificate). May be omitted if
; you do not want to verify the peer.
;cacert_file = /full/path/to/cacertf
; The verification fun (optional) if not specified, the default
; verification fun will be used.
;verify_fun = {Module, VerifyFun}
; maximum peer certificate depth
;ssl_certificate_max_depth = 1
```

After restarting the CouchDb instance I can still access the service through regular HTTP, but when I try using HTTPS it just loads forever. If I open the log file I find the following entries:

```
2020-04-22T09:02:52Z couchdb.server[55847]: [error] 2020-04-22T09:02:52.403204Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.29802.2065> -------- application: mochiweb, "Accept failed error", "{error,{options,{certfile,\"/ssl/bws2020.crt\",{error,enoent}}}}"
2020-04-22T09:02:52Z couchdb.server[55847]: [error] 2020-04-22T09:02:52.404265Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.29802.2065> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.29802.2065>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {error,accept_failed} at mochiweb_acceptor:init/4(line:75) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:247); initial_call: {mochiweb_acceptor,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, ancestors: [https,couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.212.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.261.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 1598, stack_size: 27, reductions: 1041
2020-04-22T09:02:52Z couchdb.server[55847]: [error] 2020-04-22T09:02:52.414818Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.30525.2065> -------- application: mochiweb, "Accept failed error", "{error,{options,{certfile,\"/ssl/bws2020.crt\",{error,enoent}}}}"
2020-04-22T09:02:52Z couchdb.server[55847]: [error] 2020-04-22T09:02:52.415121Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.30525.2065> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.30525.2065>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {error,accept_failed} at mochiweb_acceptor:init/4(line:75) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:247); initial_call: {mochiweb_acceptor,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2',...]}, ancestors: [https,couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.212.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.261.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 1598, stack_size: 27, reductions: 1041
```

If I understand the logs correctly it means that it cannot find the certificate file. However I have verified the path multiple times and even chmod'ed the certificate and key files to 777, but the issue remains.

We are using CouchDb 2.3.1 on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Can someone help me understand what causes this error?

Comment: Please do not post images of text. They are hard to read, and for the visually impaired they are impossible to read. They also cannot be indexed or searched. Just copy/paste the text directly into the post.

Comment: Aside from that, server configuration questions are off-topic here. This site is for programming questions. ServerFault is a better fit for this question.